# Visited link CSS

Tags: css

I'm creating a website for a small company. The project was started by an amateur website designer, and I have taken over the project.

Every day I discover new flaws in the css, but now I've something odd, and I cannot find the cause.

The problem is the link on the webshop page of this website: http://o-vita.nl/webshop.php

Beneath "Link naar onze webshop:" there is a link that stays white when I click on it. I cannot find the cause of this in the css...

Since I don't know where the problem lies, I cannot show you the code. You have to find it by viewing the source code of the page.

Answer (score 1):

In the file [css.css](http://o-vita.nl/css/css.css) (which is in the folder "css", which gets redundant fast...):

```
.footer a:link, a:active, a:focus, a:visited {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

I think the big problem here is how these rules are being referenced.  This line:

```
.footer a:link, a:active, a:focus, a:visited
```

Basically means:

- An `a:link` in a `.footer` element
- ANY `a:active` on the page
- ANY `a:focus` on the page
- or ANY `a:visited` on the page.

I'll bet the latter three selectors in that rule should also be limited to `.footer`, but that's up to you.

Comment: David, you've got it completely :D Thank you very much, the problem is solved now! Indeed the latter a:active, a:focus and a:visited where applied to the whole site. I created seperate selectors for them now ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
.footer a:link, a:active, a:focus, a:visited
```

Make a:visited an alternate CSS entry with a different color and remove it from here. Like:

```
.footer a:visited {color:blue}
```

Also the whole line is wrong as it looks like they are trying to do:

```
.footer a:link, .footer a:active, .footer a:focus, .footer a:visited
```

But messaged up the syntax.

Comment: What the OP is referencing does not appear to be part of the footer div, it looks to be part of the kolom-midden div.

Answer (score 0):

In your `css.css` file, line 249, you have a rule:

```
.footer a:link, a:active, a:focus, a:visited
{
   color: white;
}
```

Change the color in that line.